# cURL SSL certificate problem when making requests to Google Places API

Tags: ssl-certificate, google-places-api

I'm currently working on a PHP project that involves making requests to the Google Places API using cURL. However, I'm running into an issue on my WAMP server where I get an "SSL certificate problem: unable to get local issuer certificate" error when trying to make requests to the API. On my online server i have this message "400. That’s an error.

Your client has issued a malformed or illegal request. That’s all we know. ""

I've tried dumping the request URL and checking it in the browser, and it seems to return a valid JSON response. I've also checked my cURL settings and made sure they're correct.

I'm not sure what's causing this issue, and I'd appreciate any help or insights on how to resolve it. Thanks in advance!

````
$depart = $_POST['departure'];
    $arrivee =  $_POST['arrival'];
   

    // Configuration de la requête à l'API de Google Places
    $api_key = 'MY_KEY';
    $request_url_depart = "https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/place/autocomplete/json?input=$depart&key=$api_key";
    $request_url_arrivee = "https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/place/autocomplete/json?input=$arrivee&key=$api_key";
   

    // Vérification que tous les champs sont remplis
   
        // Tous les champs sont remplis, traiter les données du formulaire

        // Envoi de la requête à l'API de Google Places pour le départ
        $curl_depart = curl_init();
        curl_setopt($curl_depart, CURLOPT_URL, $request_url_depart);
        curl_setopt($curl_depart, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, true);
        $api_response_depart = curl_exec($curl_depart);
        curl_close($curl_depart);

        // Envoi de la requête à l'API de Google Places pour l'arrivée
        $curl_arrivee = curl_init();
        
        curl_setopt($curl_arrivee, CURLOPT_URL, $request_url_arrivee);

        curl_setopt($curl_arrivee, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, true);
        $api_response_arrivee = curl_exec($curl_arrivee);
        curl_close($curl_arrivee);
        if ($api_response_arrivee === false) {
            echo 'Erreur de requête cURL : ' . curl_error($curl_arrivee);
        }
        var_dump($api_response_arrivee);
        // Traitement de la réponse de l'API pour le départ
        $response_data_depart = json_decode($api_response_depart);
        if ($response_data_depart->status != 'OK') {
            // Adresse de départ invalide
            $_SESSION['erreur']['departure'] = 'Adresse de départ invalide';
        }

        // Traitement de la réponse de l'API pour l'arrivée
        $response_data_arrivee = json_decode($api_response_arrivee);
        // var_dump($response_data_arrivee);
        if ($response_data_arrivee->status != 'OK') {
            // Adresse d'arrivée invalide
            $_SESSION['erreur']['arrival'] = 'Adresse d\'arrivée invalide';
        }```
````

I tried to add this

```
curl_setopt($curl_depart, CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYPEER, false);
curl_setopt($curl_arrivee, CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYPEER, false);

And still get error 400
```

Comment: Have you urlencoded the parameters `$depart` and `$arrivee`?